# Is there a maximum length for a query text in OracleCommand.CommandText?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, dataprovider

I am querying a Oracle Database (version 9 or 10) from C# using the `OracleCommand` class.

```
String query = GetQuery(); //may produce quite lenghty queries...
OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = query;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

This class is in the `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` namespace in `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` (version "10.2.0.100"), which is from Oracle, not Microsoft. It's quite old, as I learned, but I do not like to change, if there is no need.

My concern is, **is there a maximum length for this query string? Is there a limit either by that class or by the underlying Oracle Database?**

*Note: I am familiar with Microsoft SQL server, but very new to Oracle.
Also I did look for docs but Google was not much of a help for this detail this time.*

Comment: In 11g I've seen queries that were several THOUSAND lines long (not written by me - the individual that wrote them is long gone, but as Shakespeare put it, "The evil that men do lives after them...").  Put another way - the limit (in 11g) is very large, and if you encounter it you've done something very, very wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oracle9i Database Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96536/ch44.htm#288033) states a limit on sql statement length:

> > 64 K maximum; particular tools may impose lower limits

[Similar page on 11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits003.htm#i288032) doesn't declare precise limitation, though:

> > The limit on how long a SQL statement can be depends on many factors, including database configuration, disk space, and memory

I believe we can be sure that 10 and 11 versions of oracle database support 64k queries.

Docs for `OracleCommand` class do not introduce any exceptions or constraints on `CommandText` length.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out on this one!